# Getting wrong number of instances with boto3 describe_instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface, boto3

I have a lambda function that describes instances that are running in AWS Account, but when I have scaled out instances by using Auto Scaling, the Lambda function returning the wrong number of instances.
To check for this:

1. I have used the same logic and created a CLI command and the CLI command gives me the correct number of instances.
   CLI command:
   aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Instance:InstanceId}' --output json --region -eu-west-1
2. After that created a python script which I have executed in the server but this is giving the same answer as of lambda function.

Putting Lambda Function Code:

```
 client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name = 'eu-west-1')
 response_dict = client.describe_instances(Filters=[
                                            {
                                                'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                                                'Values':['running']
                                            }
                                            ])
    
instances_list = response_dict['Reservations']
result_dict={}
for instance_dict in instances_list:
        instanceDetailsresult_dict = {}
        instance_role=None
        instance = instance_dict['Instances'][0]
        instanceId = instance['InstanceId']
        print(instanceId)
```

Note:
This is just a code snippet, all libraries are included.

Comment: First step in any problem like this should be to print out the entire response you got from the API you're using (print `response_dict` in this case). That will show you everything that was returned and will often highlight the erroneous assumption you have made about the returned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list: `instance_dict['Instances'][0]` and you are only getting the first instance out of that list. I suggest iterating over that list.